# What pattern should I use for word-like movement?

Tags: regular-expression, pattern

Given a line of text like the following

```
let FindTargetsByRegexp = { re -> {lnums -> s:_FindTargetsByRegexp(re, lnums) }}
```

I want the expression

```
\(\n\|[^A-Za-z]\)\zs\S
```

to stop on the same word boundaries that you would stop on with `w` or `b`. Vim features `\<` but it has a different definition (alphabetical only).

One such problem case occurs on `{lnum` in the above example, it will stop on `{` but not `l`. I'm trying to say with my expression that as long as the character before wasn't alphabetical, and the character on wasn't a space, it should be a match. It's the reverse case for `(r`, it stops on r, but not (.

I think my understanding is broken somewhere. But basically why doesn't `\A\zs\S` do the trick? `{` is non-alphabetical, `l` not a whitespace.

Ah, it's to do with what's already been consumed by the parser. `\A\@<=\S` (a look behind) works to solve the `{l` case, but my idea can't cover the `sometext(r` scenario (due to alphabetical before `(`), and of course `->` behaving like a full word is even trickier. It might be better not to do this particular map with a regexp, curious how vim defines it with `w`. I need some way to group like characters together and say any character not like it.

`\(\A\@<=\S\|\a\@<=[^ A-z]\)` gets really close... only case is doesn't do well is `->`, maybe possible but hard to think through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we must understand how exactly vim implements the `w` command.

To start with, vim assigns every character a "class," where numerically: blank = 0, punctuation = 1, word = 2, emoji = 3, etc.  For this answer, we will ignore unicode and emoji.  In ASCII, blanks are space, tab, and null.  Word characters are those in `iskeyword` or `\k`.  Punctuation is most of everything else.  The rules are more complex with unicode.

When pressing `w`, vim follows these rules

1. Always move one character at least.
2. If the cursor's class was `> 0`, then we continue to scan forward until we meet a character of a different class.  If crossing a line, stop.  If the line is empty, the cursor will end here.
3. Finally, if the cursor is now on a blank, go to the next non-blank, whatever class that may be.

With this we can create an *approximate* regular expression.  The goal is to find situations where the class changed, either from blank to word, or non-punctuation to punctuation.

```
/\<\|\(^$\)\|\([^[:keyword:][:space:]]\@<![^[:keyword:][:space:]]\)
```

Breaking this down,

```
/\<               handles all the word boundaries
     \(^$\)       handles empty lines
             \( [keyword, space, other]   [not keyword, or space]\)
```

We use `[^[:keyword:][:space:]]` to mean essentially punctuation.  `[:keyword:]` is the same as `\k` but the latter cannot go inside a character class.